# create installable trigger (GAS) to run at 'f' frequency starting from 't' time

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

i have created six `getData` functions that each make an API call to differing services (four RESTful JSON, two SOAP XML). for each `getData` function, i have created a `setTrigger` function, that looks a little like this...

```
function setGenerationTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('generationControl')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(30)
      .create();
}
```

i have created a separate `createSchedule` function, which deletes all existing triggers and executes each of the `setTrigger` functions. of the six triggers, i need three of them to run `.everyMinutes(30)`, two to run `.everyHours(2)`, and the last to run `.everyHours(6)`. this executes as i'd expect and the triggers run at the desired intervals starting from when the `createSchedule` runs.

the problem that i want to solve is that i want these `setTrigger` functions to be staggered, for example:

- one `.everyMinutes(30)` to start at 12:00 (12:30, 13:00, 13:30, etc)
- one `.everyMinutes(30)` to start at 12:10 (12:40, 13:10, 13:40, etc)
- one `.everyMinutes(30)` to start at 12:20 (12:50, 13:20, 13:50, etc)
- one `.everyHours(2)` to start at 12:00 (14:00, 16:00, 18:00, etc)
- one `.everyHours(2)` to start at 13:00 (15:00, 17:00, 19:00, etc)

i hoped it would be as easy as adding:

- using `.atHour(12)` but this will only run daily during that hour
- using `.atMinute(10)` but this errors as this is not a valid method

can this be done from Google Apps Script using a single function to execute? or do i just have to manually schedule each trigger from the desired point in time?
or alternatively is there another/better way of achieving this same result?

Comment: @JSmith thanks for the quick response. i feared that might be the case, but was secretly hoping that i was just misusing or misinterpretting one of the existing methods :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is what i've settled on... first up there is the function that deletes all existing triggers and kicks off a staggered schedule.

```
function startTriggers() {
  deleteTriggers();
  var d = new Date();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("startNow")
    .timeBased()
    .at(d) // using .at() as GAS doesn't accept .after(0) / .after(0 * 60 * 1000)
    .create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("startIn10")
    .timeBased()
    .after(10 * 60 * 1000)
    .create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("startIn60")
    .timeBased()
    .after(60 * 60 * 1000)
    .create();
}
```

then for each of these triggers, i created a separate function which nests triggers for each of the API calls, like so.

```
function startNow() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('huntlyControl')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(2)
      .create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('generationControl')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(30)
      .create();
}
function startIn10() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('hvdcControl')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(30)
      .create();
}
function startIn60() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('huntlyControl2')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(2)
      .create();
}
```

the outcome is a schedule of triggers that looks like this...
[image: trigger-schedule]
the `Disabled` triggers are the 'staggered schedule' i create at the start and will disappear after midnight, so there's no concerns of them recreating/retriggering each day. in fact my trigger schedule now looks like the following, without me having to do any manual tidy ups.
[image: final-schedule]
thanks very much @JSmith for your answer, whilst i didn't use it in full i gave it a vote up for providing the inspiration here.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("everydayCreate")
   .timeBased()
   .at(dStart)
   .create();

ScriptApp.newTrigger("everyDayDelete")
   .timeBased()
   .at(dStop)
   .create();

function everydayCreate(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("everyMinutes")
     .timeBased()
     .everyMinutes(30)
     .create();
}

function everyDayDelete()
{
    //filter everyMinutes Trigger(s) then
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
}

function everyMinutes(){
 //main process
}
```

**NOTE**

at(Date) has a 15 minutes rounding error.

> Specifies when the trigger will run (plus or minus 15 minutes).

**REFERENCE**

[at(Date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#at(Date))

[everyMinutes(Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyMinutes(Integer))

Comment: ooo that looks interesting! then to add the 10min stagger effect maybe i could use ```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("func1")
  .timeBased()
  .at(d)
  .create();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("func2")
  .timeBased()
  .at(d + (10 * 60 * 1000))
  .create();
```
will give that a try and report back

Comment: you could also create nested triggers one that creates an `everyMinutes` trigger every days and another one that deletes triggers every day at at a certain time. Just an idea

Comment: i just tried combining `.at(d)` with `.everyMinutes(30)` but GAS doesn't like that. i got excited about your amendment but in practice it schedules all the 30min functions to run at the same time (unless i've misunderstood the solution) but i want to have them start 10mins apart. i think the nested triggers is the solution, but i just need to request them in a different order (maybe)... my brain is frazzled for now though so i'll take another look when i get home. thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes please try the second solution I'll delete the first one from my post. Thanks

Comment: @TheMaster he still can create 18 triggers with my solution

Comment: update: i'm trialling nested triggers at the moment. my main `setTriggers()` function runs 'deleteTriggers()` to remove all existing triggers, then runs `.newTrigger("startNow")` using `.at(d)` where `d = new Date()`. then it runs `.newTrigger("startIn10")` using `.after(10 * 60 * 1000)`. then finally it runs `.newTrigger("startIn60")` using `.after(60 * 60 * 1000)`.

 `startNow()` schedules `first30mTask()` and `first2hrTask()`. `startIn10()` schedules `second30mTask()`. `startIn60()` schedules `second2hTask()`. all of which gives a staggered start effect.

Comment: so far this ^^ is working well, i'm just waiting to see what happens with the startNow / startin10 / startIn60 trigger after midnight. just want to make sure new triggers aren't created each day. if tthey aren't recreated, then i'll add an answer with my full solution.