# Run installable trigger for fixed amount of time

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

How can I run my time based trigger after a certain amount of time. Let's say I would like to start the trigger right now and stop after two weeks. How can I implement that to the installable trigger? Is it even possible? I'd like to know.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(10)
  .create();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create installable trigger (GAS) to run at 'f' frequency starting from 't' time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624571/create-installable-trigger-gas-to-run-at-f-frequency-starting-from-t-time)

Comment: You need to use add an additional trigger to call a function to delete triggers. Spend some time learning how to delete triggers. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of  your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to have a function for deleting the trigger and storing the trigger ID in the User Properties.

So you could do something along the lines of this:

```
function createTrigger() {

  var trigObj = ScriptApp.newTrigger("test")
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(7)
  .create();

  var props = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var endDate = new Date;
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 14);

  props.setProperty('trigId', trigObj.getUniqueId());
  props.setProperty('trigEnd', endDate);
}

function remTrig(){
  var props = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperties();
  var now = new Date;
  var trigs = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (now.getDate() == new Date(props['trigEnd']).getDate()){
    Logger.log('Trigger will be deleted');
    for (var i = 0; i < trigs.length; i++) {
      if (trigs[i].getUniqueId() == props['trigId']){
        Logger.log(`Deleting ${trigs[i].getUniqueId()}`);
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigs[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  else
    Logger.log(`Trigger to be deleted on ${props['trigEnd']}`);
}
```

Obviously the trigger check and deletion would have to happen somewhere inside of the function your trigger is calling or you would need a separate daily trigger for the `remTrig()` function checking if it's time to delete it.

A few considerations to keep in mind is that this sample is meant for a single trigger per user if you use the first method. For a daily check if it's time to remove the trigger you'd need to have the function that creates the trigger to create a second one for the deletion check.